# Eclipse Pydev not loading an external module, terminal works fine

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm running Eclipse Juno with Pydev. I compiled an egg package that imports a C library using ctypes. It works fine from the terminal, but when run from inside Eclipse I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PhreeqPy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/phreeqpy/iphreeqc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/pywork/fddarcy/src/fddarcy.py", line 75, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/src/pywork/fddarcy/src/fddarcy.py", line 35, in main
    freak  =phreeqc_mod.IPhreeqc()    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PhreeqPy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/phreeqpy/iphreeqc/phreeqc_dll.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.phreeqc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After reloading all libraries in Pydev Eclipse is not even giving errors when importing the module, but it doesn't load the module. Just to be extra clear, everything works fine from the terminal.

EDIT: I think that the problem is in the way Eclipse is calling python. Is it any different from the way python is called from the terminal?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you may need to add it to the PYTHONPATH within Eclipse.

Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python

Add your python.exe or run autoconfig and then add the libraries you need.

Comment: Thanks, but already done that. All other python programs without that module work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is seeing the ctypes module, it's just that ctypes can't find the DLL.

The reason for this is that eclipse doesn't necessarily use your system's environment variables.  To remedy this problem, you need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH within Eclipse.

Step 1. Figure out where "libimf.so" is on your system. On Linux, you can use:

```
 locate libimf.so
```

in a terminal. That should give you the directory. For example, say the file is at "/home/sweetlibraries/libimf.so" .

Step 2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Eclipse*:

- Right click on the python file that you're running that gives this error.
- Click "properties"
- Click "Run/Debug Settings"
- You should see some configuration for the file. For me, it's "project_name python_file_name.py". Select it.
- Click "Environment"
- Click "New"
- Set Name to "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
- Set Value to wherever you found libimf.so, e.g. "/home/sweetlibraries/"
- Click "OK" to get out of all those menus.

Now when you run it, it should work. If not, make sure you use the right "run configuration". Click the little down arrow next to the big, green "run" arrow. and select the configuration name (e.g. "project_name python_file_name.py").

*I'm using LiClipse, but I think the menu structure should be identical.